# How to set Firefox to block window.name

Tags: firefox

I am attempting to modify my Firefox profile so it does not release so much confidential and private data to websites without the use of addons as I don't trust them.  Of particular interest is window.name I am attempting to restrict it's access.  I have modified my user.js file within my firefox profile with the below code.

```
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.enable", false);
user_pref("browser.cache.memory.enable", false);
user_pref("browser.display.use_document_fonts", 0);
user_pref("browser.search.defaultenginename", "Ixquick HTTPS");
user_pref("browser.search.selectedEngine", "Ixquick HTTPS");
user_pref("browser.search.suggest.enabled", false);
user_pref("browser.sessionhistory.max_entries", 2);
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.cbc.ca/");
user_pref("browser.tabs.warnOnClose", false);
user_pref("dom.battery.enabled", false);
user_pref("general.appname.override", "Netscape");
user_pref("general.appversion.override", "5.0 (X11)");
user_pref("general.buildID.override", "20140315085348");
user_pref("general.oscpu.override", "Linux i686");
user_pref("general.platform.override", "");
user_pref("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0");
user_pref("general.warnOnAboutConfig", false);
user_pref("geo.enabled", false);
user_pref("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 1);
user_pref("network.dns.disablePrefetch", true);
user_pref("network.dns.disablePrefetchFromHTTPS", true);
user_pref("network.http.pipelining", true);
user_pref("network.http.pipelining.ssl", true);
user_pref("network.http.referer.XOriginPolicy", 1);
user_pref("network.http.sendRefererHeader", 1);
user_pref("network.prefetch-next", false);
user_pref("plugin.default.state", 0);
user_pref("plugin.state.flash", 1);
user_pref("plugin.state.java", 0);
user_pref("privacy.clearOnShutdown.cache", true);
user_pref("privacy.clearOnShutdown.cookies", true);
user_pref("privacy.clearOnShutdown.downloads", true);
user_pref("privacy.clearOnShutdown.formdata", true);
user_pref("privacy.clearOnShutdown.history", true);
user_pref("privacy.clearOnShutdown.sessions", true);
user_pref("privacy.donottrackheader.enabled", true);
user_pref("privacy.sanitize.sanitizeOnShutdown", true);
user_pref("webgl.disabled", true);

user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "js");

user_pref("capability.policy.javascript.enabled", "noAccess");
user_pref("capability.policy.js.sites", "http://ip-check.info https://www.facebook.com https://facebook.com https://stackoverflow.com");
user_pref("capability.policy.js.javascript.enabled", "sameOrigin");

user_pref("capability.policy.Window.name.set", "allAccess");
user_pref("capability.policy.Window.name.get", "sameOrigin");
```

Everything works fine except for the last two lines, all javascript is disabled except on the websites I have specifically allowed via js.sites.  I have tried many different variants for window.name and can not restrict it in anyway, shape or form.  I have tried default.window.name, htmldocument.window.name plus many others, none work.  I want to make it so any website can set window.name but only the website who sets it can get that attribute.

My questions are two fold, one, is restricting window.name in the manner I am attempting possible, and two, if it is possible what am I doing wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla removed the capabilities system from Gecko quite a long time ago: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789224

The ones controlling javascript execution were always a special-case use of the "capability." namespace so those were left, but the true fine-grained object capabilities are gone.

You might be able to restrict access to Window.name from an add-on, but you'd probably have to create it; I can't think of any that already do that.

Comment: thank you, both jondonym extension and the tor extension will block window.name but they are not available as separate downloads, you have to install the appropriate browser and scoop the extension from such browser and install it in your own firefox.  If you use either extension outside of a the tor or jondonym network, you get a bunch of warnings each time you start Firefox.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the NoScrip Addon. When installed, go to about:config (the trick can not be done by the settings UI) and look for noscript.jsHack. As value you could enter for example 
window.name=123456.
The content of noscript.jsHack is javasript code which is executed every time when you visit a new site.

If you need to define exceptions, look for noscript.jsHackRegExp and enter an regular expression (no subdomains supported), e. g.:
^([^.]*).(?!(site1.com|site2.org|site3.net))(.*)

Answer (score 0):

The firefox addon Random Agent Spoofer can block window.name. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/random-agent-spoofer/ You'll have to use the github version though. There is a link to the github version on that page.